# iterating ultrapowers of C*-algebras

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, ultrapowers

Let $A$ be something interesting like the C*-algebra of compact operators on a separable infinite-dimensional Hilbert space and let $A^1$ be an ultrapower of $A$. Then $A^1$ is a primitive C*-algebra strictly containing $A$ (Ge and Hadwin). Now let $A^2$ be an ultrapower of $A^1$. Then $A^2$ is a primitive C*-algebra containing $A^1$, presumably strictly. In the same way we may define $A^3$, $A^4$, etc. Since $A^n$ contains $A^{n-1}$ we may define an inductive limit $A^{\omega}$, and then continue transfinitely with $A^{{\omega} +1}$ etc.

My question is, Does the process ever stabilise? If so does it stabilise at some finite step, or at $\omega$ or at the first uncountable ordinal?

Comment: This might, perhaps, depend on the ultrafiltera used at each atep.

Comment: In light of my answer, could you clarify what you mean by stabilize? The successive ultrapower maps are never isomorphisms, but perhaps you just want the models to be externally isomorphic. 

Comment: @ Joel. Yes, I was just thinking of external isomorphism. So in my question, I am interested in whether $A^1$ and $A^2$ are isomorphic as C*-algebras.

Comment: @Joel. Does "externally isomorphic" just mean "isomorphic"?  I'm not familiar with this term.

Comment: By "externally" isomorphic, I had just meant isomorphic, but not necessarily by the ultapower map under consideration. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the C*-algebra ultrapower construction, instead of identifying two sequences if they agree on a set in the ultrafilter, you identify two sequences if their difference goes to zero along the ultrafilter.  You also throw out those sequences whose norm goes to infinity along the ultrafilter.

I think the simple answer to the question is that *any* infinite dimensional C*-algebra is properly contained in *any* ultrapower coming from a free (nonprincipal) ultrafilter.  In fact this will be true of any infinite dimensional Banach space, as a simple consequence of the fact that its unit ball is not precompact.  We can find a sequence of vectors in the unit ball such that the distance between any two of them is at least 1/2, and this will always give rise to a new element in the ultrapower (it is not identified with any constant sequence). So no, the process never stabilizes.

Comment: The argument of your second paragaph is showing that the ultrapower map itself is not an isomorphism. But this is not the same as showing that the ultrapower algebra is not isomorphic to the original algebra. 

Comment: For example, in analogy with the usual first-order ultrapower construction, it seems likely that if the CH holds, then the double ultrapower of a $C^*$ algebra of size continuum will be externally isomorphic to any single ultrapower. 

Comment: @Joel. But in the original post, he is unambiguously asking whether you reach a point where the natural containment is not strict. Otherwise the notation $A^\omega$ doesn't even make sense.

Comment: I now understand from Nik's answer that the natural containment is strict at each stage, so in this sense the process never stabilizes. On the other hand, as far as constructing new C*-algebras is concerned, the process 'stabilizes' as soon at the ultrapower is isomorphic as a C*-algebra to its predecessor. So I am very interested in this question of whether $A^1$ and $A^2$ are C*-isomorphic (under CH).

Comment: @Douglas. Well, we know that under CH any two countable ultrapowers of a separable C*-algebra are isomorphic. So the question is whether an ultrapower of an ultrapower is an ultrapower.  That's certainly true for ordinary cartesian powers --- a countable power of a countable power is a countable power. So we have to check whether that trivial isomorphism induces an isomorphism at the (C*) ultrapower level. It seems to me there is no problem here; just check it, it works.  So yes, $A^1$ and $A^2$ are isomorphic under CH.

Comment: Nik, the classical ultrapower of an ultrapower is indeed an ultrapower, by the product ultrafilter in the plane, but in the $C^*$ ultrapower case, where we restrict the functions and broaden the equivalence relation, we seem definitely to lose the saturation property that enables the CH back-and-forth argument showing that the ultrapowers are all isomorphic. Are you saying that the back-and-forth argument nevertheless goes through for these $C^*$-ultrapowers under CH for algebras of size continuum?

Comment: Joel --- Yes, Ge and Hadwin did this. (Ultraproducts of C∗-algebras, in Recent advances in operator theory and related topics (Szeged, 1999), 305–326, Oper. Theory Adv. Appl., 127, Birkhäuser, Basel, 2001.)

Comment: Great! Then it seems to be a proof that the iterated ultrapowers (for seperable $C^*$ algebras) stabilize after one step, assuming the continuum hypothesis. 

Comment: Right, it looks okay to me too.

Answer (score 1):

Iterated ultrapowers are intensely studied in set theory, and this
topic is fundamental to the theory of large cardinal inner model
theory.

The usual set-theoretic perspective on ultrapowers is broad-minded
about what it is that we are actually taking the ultrapower of:
why bother taking the ultrapower only of the integers, or only of
the reals, or only of a particular $C^*$-algebra, when one can
take the ultrapower of the entire set-theoretic universe? For a
given ultrafilter $U$, if you are entertaining the ultrapower of a
specific mathematical structure by $U$, then why not add all
possible relations on that structure as well, for this will give
nonstandard analogues of those relations in the ultrapower;
indeed, why not add all possible sets of relations and so on,
iterating transfinitely? The point is that all ultrapowers of any
structure by the same ultrafilter fit together coherently into a
grand ultrapower of the entire universe.

Meanwhile, for a given ultrafilter $U$, there are several ways to
proceed with iterated ultrapowers of the universe $V$, and from
this perspective the question is ambiguous about what it means to
iterate the ultrapower transfinitely.

Let me explain. On the one hand, the most typical way to proceed
is by means of what it called the *internal* ultrapower. Having
started with $V=M_0$ and formed the $\alpha$-th ultrapower
$M_\alpha$, one has the canonical map $j_{0,\alpha}:V\to
M_\alpha$. The internal perspective is to view $j_{0,\alpha}(U)$
as an ultrafilter $U_\alpha$ inside the model $M_\alpha$, and then
form the next structure $M_{\alpha+1}$ as the internal ultrapower
of $M_\alpha$ by the ultrafilter $U_\alpha$. At limit stages, one
takes the direct limit and continues iterating.

Alternatively, one may form the external ultrapower $M_{\alpha+1}$
as the ultrapower of $M_\alpha$ via the original ultrafilter $U$. It seems that this is what you had in mind.

For the finite ultrapowers, the two ways of proceeding, either
internally or externally, actually give rise to isomorphic models,
even though this is not obvious. Nevertheless, the resulting
system of maps $j_{n,m}:M_n\to M_m$ are definitely not the same,
and this difference applies even when taking the ultrapower of the
integers or of your $C^*$-algebra. Furthermore, when one takes the
limit model $M_\omega$, then the internal iteration can be very
different from the external iteration, and no longer isomorphic.
For example, in the large cardinal context of iterating the
ultrapower by a normal measure on a measurable cardinal, Kunen
proved famously that all the internal iterated ultrapowers are
well-founded, but the external iterations are definitely
ill-founded at $\omega$. Similar and analogous differences arise
even for ultrafilters on $\omega$.

Set theorists often also commonly consider more complicated
systems of iterating ultrapowers, where one uses different
ultrafilters at each step, often on different underlying sets,
leading to the concept of extender embeddings. The highly
developed subject known as large cardinal inner model theory is
about the fundamental nature of these extender embeddings and the
universes of set theory that one can build in this way. For
example, the concept of iterating a measure "out of the universe"
is an elementary part of this theory: one has an ultrafilter and
considers the proper-class-length iterated internal ultrapower by
that ultrafilter, looking at the residue of what is left behind
below the successive critical points of the embeddings.

In addition, Haim Gaifman showed how to form the iteration of an
ultrafilter along any linear order, not just the well-founded
iterations. Thus, one can form a system of models that is the
iteration of an ultrafilter along the integers, or the rationals
or even the surreal numbers.

There is another ambiguity in your question, concerning what it
means to reach a fixed point. On the one hand, neither the
internal nor the external iteration ever reaches a fixed point, if
what is meant is that the ultrapower map
$j_{\alpha,\alpha+1}:M_\alpha\to M_{\alpha+1}$ is an isomorphism,
since this map is never an isomorphism unless the structure is
smaller than the degree of completeness of the ultrafilter. In
particular, if you are using a nonprincipal ultrafilter on
$\mathbb{N}$, then no ultrapower map of an infinite structure, such as your $C^*$-algebra, is
an isomorphism. So in this strong sense, the process never
terminates, no matter how long you proceed, and your question has a negative answer.

But if you seek a weaker fixed-point concept, where you have only
that $M_\alpha$ is isomorphic to $M_{\alpha+1}$, but not
necessarily by the ultrapower map connecting these structures, then there can be a positive answer already at the second step. Specifically, if the CH holds, then the ultrapower of any
structure of size continuum by a nonprincipal ultrafilter on
$\mathbb{N}$ is isomorphic to the two-step-iterated-ultrapower,
because these are both saturated structures of size $\omega_1$ and
with the same theory, so they are isomorphic by a back-and-forth
argument. In this sense, your question has a positive answer.

If you don't have CH, then I'd have to think a bit harder about
where one reaches a fixed point.

Comment: I seem to recall that in the Ge-Hadwin paper to which Douglas refers, and indeed in other papers on operator algebras, the definition of a $C^\ast$-algebraic ultrapower is not quite the same as the ultrapower in the set-theoretic sense. However (a) I could be misremembering (b) your comments might still apply.

Comment: On further reflection, I guess that the ultraproducts being used by Ge and Hadwin would be along the lines of Henson's constructions/set-up. Do your comments still apply there?

Comment: Yemon, yes, that could be right. The OP did seem, however, to suggest a certain flexibility with what his structure was---"Let $A$ be something interesting...."---so I was imagining $A$ as a first-order structure, whose ultrapowers I understand better than $C^*$-algebras. But I think that even for $C^*$-ultrapowers, the ultrapower map itself will never be an isomorphism, so my first answer still applies, and for the second answer, if the CH holds then I find it likely that the saturation arguments still apply to get the isomorphism for the weak fixed point concept. 

Comment: I'm sorry that I am just not sufficiently familiar with the modified construction for ultrapowers of $C^*$-algebras. I am imagining that as in Hans Schoutens cataproduct work they take a standard part at some point to turn hyperreals back into reals? I find it likely that this wouldn't affect either of my answers: the ultrapower map itself will never be an isomorphism, and if CH holds, then the resulting models will be isomorphic; but I'd have to know the exact construction to be sure.